# How to determine if the type of a FieldDeclarationSyntax is an interface in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Let's say there is a class that contains a private field of interface type.
When analyzing the code above with Roslyn, how is it possible to determine if the type behind `FieldDeclarationSyntax` is an interface? Using the code below to retrieve the `ISymbol` of the field declaration, I cannot find any property like `IsInterface` or similar.

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

public class SampleClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str =
            @"
            namespace Sample
            {
                public interface IBar
                {
                    void Do();
                }

                public class Foo
                {
                    private IBar _bar;
                }
            }";

        var syntaxTree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(str);

        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Sample", new[] { syntaxTree });

        var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree, true);

        var classDeclarationSyntax =
        semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First();

        var fieldDeclarationSyntax = classDeclarationSyntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<FieldDeclarationSyntax>().First();

        var declaredSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(fieldDeclarationSyntax.Declaration.Variables.First());

        // declaredSymbol (ISymbol) contains properties like IsDefinition, IsVirtual etc. but nothing like IsInterface.
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking such kinds of questions, please provide an [mcve] so that people willing to answer can easily verify their answer works without having to create their own testing code.

Comment: @NineBerry Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling GetTypeInfo on fieldDeclarationSyntax.Declaration.Type did the trick finally. 
Complete working example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

public class SanpleClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str =
            @"
            namespace Sample
            {
                public interface IBar
                {
                    void Do();
                }

                public class Foo
                {
                    private IBar _bar;
                }
            }";

        var syntaxTree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(str);

        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("Sample", new[] { syntaxTree });

        var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree, true);

        var classDeclarationSyntax =
            semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().First();

        var fieldDeclarationSyntax = classDeclarationSyntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<FieldDeclarationSyntax>().First();

        var typeKind = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(fieldDeclarationSyntax.Declaration.Type).Type.TypeKind;

        var isInterface = typeKind == TypeKind.Interface;

        Console.WriteLine($"Is Interface: {isInterface}");
    }
}
```